# ASP.NET- 2nd Postback not happening via SiteMap link?

Tags: asp.net, html, meta-tags

**NOTE: I have an aspx ASPX page which is rendered from a SiteMap. 1st time the POSTBACK happens, but subsequently in same sessions, POSTBACK does not get fired.**

HACK (not working) - 
I have the refresh meta tag like this inside the HTML  tag

```
<html>
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="2">
  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Main.css" id="style"/>
 </head>
</html>
```

When I am visiting this ASPX page, I want this META tag to be called only ONCE. So, I was trying the following code in OnLoadComplete event ?-

```
        HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
        HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
        head.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
```

But, that does not work. Any idea why is the postback not happening ? 
d

Answer (score 0):

< META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="2">

is suitable for those web site where we continuously want to refresh page after a particular time interval, here in your scenario if you want to refresh whole page only once then you can
do two thing 
*). call Response's method like this

```
Response.Redirect("currentPage.aspx")
```

*). In Page_Load method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["refresh"] != null)
    {
        HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
        HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
        head.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    else
        Session["refresh"] = "not null";
}
```

Comment: Jeevan, Problem is I do not get a post back when I land on this aspx page. So, I was putting the META REFRESH Tag for a POSTBACK and then I dont want any further POSTBACKS.

Comment: @Angshuman- can u post your complete code because i coud not understand why u are not geting PostBack because in a normal scenario it will post back, your question is not clear.

Comment: This Page is rendered from a SiteMap link and once loaded, 1st time Postback happens. But second time when I click on the Link, POSTBACK is not fired.

Comment: @Angshuman: Your problem is still not clear, now as far what i can understand by your question for that i created a scenario where i have a master page with a menu which is binded to sitemapdatasource which has web.Sitemap with 2 url Default1.aspx and default2.aspx now i also have home page with master page, Now i run app. load home page with menu, now if i click on delfault.aspx's menu item then page loads and if i again click on same menu item then i again get a post back on same page ( default.aspx ). Is this the same scenario which you have if no then cleare your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="2">` should also have a `runat="server"` attribute in order for ASP.NET to interact with it.

**UPDATE**
The second time it is not a ASP.NET postback, the page is not being retrieved using POST but using GET.  Maybe use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.com/myurl?myvariable=XYZ"/>`, so when it refreshes, it will append some variable. On your "postback" you check for the existence of that variable.

Comment: Gidon, Problem is that why the 2nd postback is not working for the Sitemap link ? hence, this was a hack which I tried. The problem is stated in BOLD.